# what assembly reference is required to use ViewModel xaml control in a normal WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to wpf and develeping a simple wpf application usinng MVVM pattern. i started with default WPF application provided by Visual Studio 2010. Now i am trying to add ViewModel xaml tag in mainWindow.xaml but it says

> ViewModel type not found . Are you missing an assembly reference

I know by installing toolkit for MVVM i can get MVVM template. But i want to how i can use viewmodel tag in a simple wpf application. Is there any assembly reference for that?

Comment: What do you mean by ViewModel tag? it is the class that implement by yourself, no need to add any reference

Comment: basically `ViewModel` is a concept and various toolkit help you implement the same. you can also implement your own as well, all you need is to implement a change notification mechanism eg. `INotifyPropertyChanged`. btw could you share the code where do you face this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic example of how we use the MVVM pattern - just add this in the 'Grid' section of the View (the .xaml file) of the template:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue}"/>
```

Now create a class in the project named 'MainViewModel', that will be your your 'ViewModel' - where the properties live that the View binds to.  Here's all you need in there:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.MyValue = "Success";
    }
}
```

Then in the code-behind (the .xaml.cs file) of that View, bind the DataContext of the View to your ViewModel.  The constructor becomes:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: thanks somehow i got confused with the toolkit blogs available for implementing MVVM

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at below snippet and help for yourself.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Regards,
KSAM